# ImageTextButton как написать

Tags: java, android, libgdx

как создать ImageTextButton, в интернете гораздо меньше информации об этом, чем о простом ImageButton, есть у кого-то пример создания этой кнопочки с текстом?

Comment: Приведите пример в виде картинки.

Comment: картинку чего? кода?

Comment: Можно же использовать обычный Button с текстом, добавить ему background , или drawableLeft,drawableRight и т.д. и  текстом

Comment: Картинку того, что хотите сделать. Из описания вообще не ясно, чего вы хотите добиться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите кнопку с фоном и текстом, вам подойдет обычная `TextButton`. `TextButtonStyle` наследует качества обычной кнопки, а именно - иметь фон-картинку.

Как сделать без скинов:

```
// Создаем стиль для кнопки
TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
// Переопределяем нужные параметры (например, up - картинка обычного состояния кнопки).
// Так же нужно задать font, опустил для краткости.
textButtonStyle.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(/*сюда передаем TextureRegion*/);
TextButton textButton = new TextButton("Тут текст кнопки", textButtonStyle);
```

Со скинами:

```
TextButton backButton = new TextButton("Текст кнопки", Utility.UI_SKIN, "default-button-with-background");
```

В json скина:

```
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle": {
    ...прочие стили TextButton
    "default-button-with-background": {
      "font": "default-font", //шрифт
      "fontColor": "black", //цвет
      "up": "buttonRegular", //название текстуры обычного состояния кнопки для фона
    },
    ...прочие стили TextButton
}
```

Comment: я и не думал, что textbutton полностью справится с моей задачей, спасибо